# Convert '0000-00-00' to 'flag' in python

Tags: excel, python-3.x, datetime

I want to convert some data of dates into the string after checking them in a specific range. I have first converted all data into type float so that it can provide output as dates format but when I applied this for the dates it shows:

```
a1 = float(a1)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '0000-00-00'
```

My whole code is:

```
import xlrd
import os.path
from datetime import datetime

date_array = []

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(os.path.join('E:\Files','SummaryLease.xlsx'))

sh = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

for i in range(1,sh.nrows):

    a1 = sh.cell_value(rowx=i, colx=80)
    if a1 is '0000-00-00':
        date_array.append('flag')
    else:
        a1 = float(a1)
        a1_as_datetime = datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(a1, wb.datemode))
        date_array.append(a1_as_datetime.date())

print(date_array)
```

How should I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't compare strings using `is` operator, use `==`.

```
if a1 == '0000-00-00':
    date_array.append('flag')
else:
    a1 = float(a1)
```

You can read more about the difference here:
[Is there a difference between `==` and `is` in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python)